# C# and SQL Commands

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create my first database application with a C# application (not website) front end and with Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition as the back end. It is actually a bird sightings database for birdwatchers.

I have set up the database with 3 tables using the schema and database designer.

I have assigned 2 fields in the 3 tables as foreign keys. I think I did it correctly but I am not sure.

I have dragged and dropped the  tables onto the main program form and have automatically created some textboxes and one listbox for data entry.

I am trying to allow selection of a bird species (field: "common name" a navchar) from the species table which would then insert the value from the primary key field in the species table (field: "speciesID" an int) as a foreign key or link into the species field (field "species" an int) in the sightings database.

I am actually struggling with the extreme basics, like how to invoke SQL commands from within C# to display one field but to select and insert a different field in the same row as a value in a different table (this is my understanding of a foreign key, correct me if I am wrong).

Sorry if I am not expressing myself well here. Please note that I am a total newbie. I am reasonably comfortable with C# (though I have not used it in over a year) but this is the first time I am throwing a SQL server into the mix.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895908  Please to enjoy

Comment: sql group functions. ... click here .... http://www.freecodeproject.com/DatabaseTutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I like to share some links to have a overview of `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `view` data from database to your window form, here you go:

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_update_form.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/f02bac79-7216-4e45-9c01-f45e0d06ce2f

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection();
MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand();   

 Conn.ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=database;Uid=root;Pwd=root";
    Cmd.Connection = Conn;
    Cmd.CommandText = "Statment";
    Conn.Open();
    // for Insert or Update or Delete
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //for Select
    Cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Conn.Close();
```